# Adding Characters to beginning and end of line that matches expression (Python)

Tags: python

Background: I am tasked with taking content from one website (mostly HTML tables), and inserting it into a wiki type site. I am able to poll the content (it is dynamic) using a REST API and get HTML formatted output. I must take this output, and convert it into Wiki Markup in order to then insert it into the new site. I am having issues with the conversion part.

Currently I am using the html2text module in my test script as below:

```
import os
import sys
import html2text

file = raw_input("File to convert: ")

h = html2text.HTML2Text()
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    dataContent = f.read()
    dataConverted = h.handle(dataContent)

with open('tempconvert', 'w') as f:
    f.write(dataConverted)
    #print dataConverted

# Add the | to the line beginnings and endings

with open('tempconvert', 'r') as f:
    tempContent = f.readlines()

with open('finalconvert', 'w') as f:
    for line in tempContent:
        if '|' in line:
            f.write('|' + line.rstrip('\n') + '| \n')
```

Now, the reason for all this input and output is because the html2text module doesn't insert a beginning or trailing "|" which the wiki syntax needs to recognize it as a table.

My questions are:

1. This is super ugly ... any way to clean this up without writing to so many temporary files?
2. When I use the final search for adding the "|", it only writes the lines it acts upon (which makes sense given the arguments). How would I get it to act upon those lines, but also keep all the other lines that it doesn't act upon?
3. It would also be awesome for me to be able to take the first line in the table instance (you can tell this because of whitespace before and after the table) and append a "||" in order to signify its a header row. Is this also possible?

Comment: You can try to use regex to do the replacement, but it won't make the code cleaner.

Comment: You can eliminate the temporary files by using `tempContent = dataConverted.split('\n')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: You can eliminate the temporary files by using [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to convert from a single string to a list of strings. This has the side effect of removing the `\n` from each line, which you will have to add back or account for later.

```
tempContent = dataConverted.split('\n')
```

2: There are two ways to fix this. First is to simply use an `else` to write the lines that you were skipping before. (No need for the `rstrip` if you use the `split` hint from above).

```
if '|' in line:
    f.write('|' + line + '| \n')
else:
    f.write(line + '\n')
```

The other way is to update the line if it needs updating, then write it in either case.

```
if '|' in line:
    line = '|' + line + '| '
f.write(line + '\n')
```

3: This is harder, because you don't just want to add those bars to *any* line that follows a blank line, you want to detect that there's a table coming up. This means you need some kind of look-ahead. Here's a little function you can use to see ahead automatically.

```
def lookahead(seq):
    current = None
    for upcoming in seq:
        if current is not None:
            yield current, upcoming
        current = upcoming
    if current is not None:
        yield current, None
```

You'd use it like this:

```
for line, upcoming in lookahead(tempContent):
    if (upcoming and '|' in upcoming) or ('|' in line):
        line = '|' + line + '|'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you! Not only did you help to solve my problem, but I also learned quite a bit from it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A first try:

```
html = html2text.HTML2Text()
input_file = raw_input('File to convert: ')

with open(input_file, 'r') as input_, open('finalconvert', 'w') as output_:
    data = input_.read()
    data_converted = html.handle(data)

    for line in data_converted.split('\n'):
        if '|' in line:
            line = "|{}|\n".format(line.rstrip())
        output_.write(line.encode())
```

This code fixes 1 and 2; but I do not understood 3.

Comment: Excellent, much cleaner! For the second question, when the output_.write is called it is only writing the lines in the file which contain the '|'. There is also normal text in this file that is omitted because it does not include '|'. I need all the text in the file, not just the lines that contain '|'. For the third question, is there a way to make the first line in the table contain double '|' instead of single. So like "for first line in match after whitespace do "||{}\n", for each additional line before more whitespace do "|{}|\n". Hopefully that makes more sense. :)